# Git post-merge hook failing through sourcetree

Tags: git, githooks, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a git post-merge hook that calls bower to install any new packages if bower.json was changed following a git merge. Now, when I do a git pull through sourcetree, sourcetree does begin to execute the hook, but it craps out when it comes time to run the actual command, which is bizarre. It does not recognize the bower command at all. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you globally install bower with the -g flag (so it can be run without referencing the binary) on the machine where this post-commit hook is running?

```
npm install -g bower
```